# RethinkDB Export table with nested fields into CSV

Tags: rethinkdb

How do you export nested fields from a RethinkDB Table.

So if my data is

```
{
    "id" : 1,
    "name" : "john",
    "phone" : {
        "work": "123456789",
        "home" : "987654321",
        "mobile" : "049876543"
    }
}
```

How can I export this to a flat CSV file with 5 columns of id, name, phone_work, phone_home, phone_mobile

```
>rethinkdb export -e PeopleDB.Contacts --format csv --fields id,name,phone_work,phone_home,phone_mobile
```

I am not sure how you reference nested fields in the export

Comment: I'm not sure that you can. See https://github.com/rethinkdb/rethinkdb/issues/3503

Comment: Yeah I don't think so. I looked at the source https://github.com/rethinkdb/rethinkdb/blob/dc595620ed32c79ddb25ff8ca18882fa69b35f8d/drivers/python/rethinkdb/_export.py. It basically just does this json.dumps(row[field]) for objects. Line 154